# Javascript prompt() has dim (faint) prompt message in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, browser, dialog, prompt

The prompt is almost unreadable (grey) on a black dialog background... surely this is not by design?

Comment: can you share some code related to prompt?

Comment: @Brad Thomas Actually am askin to post related html and css code or javascript code to get an idea why its displayin as dim?

Comment: @Matrix His code is immaterial. The appearance of the `prompt` dialog is completely up to the browser.

Comment: @Peter Olson oh ok thanks for information. actually i thought prompt is displayin as dim in one situation. If its browser control then may be we need to have some libraries as you mentioned. :-)

Comment: Yeah Matrix I don't think my code is affecting it. I'd like to know if that property of the Android browser is controllable in some way. Its gonna be frustrating to have to design some custom dialogs just to deal with this browser weirdness, because then I'm going to have to test for device somehow or replace dialogs across all browsers. The standard dialogs on other browsers and just fine and I love them, e.g safari, dolphin etc.

Comment: A screen shot of the issue wouldn't go amiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design--and unchangeable (unless there are proprietary properties of the `prompt` function that I've never heard of.)

The appearance of the prompt dialog is under the complete control of the browser. If you want something more customizable I'm sure there are plenty of custom dialog libraries available.

Comment: Yeah, i figured it was a browser issue, but it must surely be a bug in the browser..??. I mean on the Razor, its almost impossible to see the text. I have the Droid X and its very dim.